# Misunderstanding about Laplace operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We know that the Laplace operator
\begin{align}
\Delta \colon H_0^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)
\end{align}
admits an inverse operator
\begin{align}
A \colon L^2(\Omega) \to H_0^1(\Omega)
\end{align}
which is bounded and then (by Poincaré inequality and Rellich embedding theorem) can be viewed as a compact operator from $L^2(\Omega)$ to $ L^2(\Omega)$.

Now I have a basic problem: since $\Delta$ is unbounded, how can $A$ be a bounded operator? Wouldn't this contradict the open mapping theorem?

Comment: How do you define $\Delta$?

Comment: $A$ is bounded with dense range; it is injective, but it is not surjective. That means that the inverse $\Delta$ has dense domain and is surjective. Both are closed, but there is no contradiction because the inverse is only densely-defined and, so, is not defined on the full complete space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the problem is the norm of the spaces where you define the operators.

The Laplace operator $\Delta$ has domain $H^2_0 (\Omega)$. If one endows this Sobolev space 
with its norm, then $\Delta:H^2_0 (\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ is bounded. So there is no 
contradiction with the open mapping thm.

On the other hand, note that we cannot apply 
the open mapping theorem to $A: L^2(\Omega) \to H^2_0(\Omega)$, if we consider the $L^2$ norm on $H^2(\Omega)$ (since it is not a Banach space).

Comment: just a little more detail about the last bit:  `The set H^2 equipped with the metric given by the L^2 norm is not a complete metric space.'